# pymongo query operator that matches everything

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm writing a pymongo query expression, and I'd like to use an operator which matches everything (regardless of whether the field exists or not).

For example, I'd like to find a value for x which makes the following two queries equivalent:

```
collection.find({'a': 2, 'b': x})
collection.find({'a': 2})
```

I understand that the best way to do this is to simply use the second query. For reasons well beyond the scope of this post that isn't possible in my case, so I'd like to figure out a value for x.

I thought of things like

```
x = {'$ne': <some large random number unlikely to occur>}
```

but they don't seem very elegant.

Comment: for nonsql-injection? ;)

Comment: Hah :) no just a boring application where it would be a total pain to have variable set of keys in the query document

Answer (score 1):

If you **must** keep the structure of your query spec like that, then there's no operator that can help you and you'll have to resort to hacks like the one you mention.

You have some choices if you relax your constraint so that you must have another field, but it does not have to use `b` as its key. For instance:

```
collection.find({
    'a': 2,
    '$or': [{'b': {'$exists': true}}, {'b': {'$exists': false}}]
})
```

...but I know that's not what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I would use:

```
db.collection.find({'a': 2, 'b': {$in: [null, false, /.*/]}})
```

It will match if 'b' is null (does not exist) or is any value (regex match for all values).

Comment: But would the regex pick up numeric values?

Comment: Nope! Just tested this, and the documentation for `$regex` says: Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching *strings* in queries :(

Comment: I guess there are solutions if we know in advance the type of `b`, for some types of `b`. But not for matching *everything*